# Spring Session with Spring Security creates two sessions

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-session

I have a Spring 4.1 web app, I use spring-security and spring session, spring session I want to use with websockets to keep the session without timeout as long as the websocket is working.

It all works fine but what I find is that I obviously have two sessions running, one for spring security and one for spring session.

This is my session.xml:

```
   <bean id="jedisConnFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
          <property name="hostName" value="localhost"/>
          <property name="port" value="6379" />
   </bean>

   <bean class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository" name="sessionRepository" >
          <constructor-arg name="redisConnectionFactory" ref="jedisConnFactory" />
          <!--<property name="defaultMaxInactiveInterval" value="60" />-->
   </bean>

   <bean class="org.springframework.session.web.http.HeaderHttpSessionStrategy" name="sessionStrategy" />

   <bean name="springSessionRepositoryFilter" class="org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter">
          <constructor-arg name="sessionRepository" ref="sessionRepository" />
   </bean>

   <bean class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration" >
          <property name="httpSessionStrategy" ref="sessionStrategy"/>
   </bean>
```

And here is my security.xml:

```
<!-- Security -->
<bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.fg.ts.base.security.userdetails.CustomUserDetailsService" />

<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder">
    <constructor-arg value="${encoder.password}" />
</bean>

<sec:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <sec:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="disabled"
                            jsr250-annotations="enabled" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" />

<!-- Exclude the resources+error+auth pages from security filter -->
<sec:http pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/images/**" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/ico/**" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/lib/**" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/auth/**" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/error/**" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/api/concordancer/search/**" security="none" />
<sec:http pattern="/concordancer/search" security="none"/>
<sec:http pattern="/assets/cdSearch.xhtml" security="none"/>
<sec:http pattern="/api/tmGroup/**" security="none"/>
<sec:http pattern="/api/reports/download/**" security="none"/>
<sec:http pattern="/api/socket/tasks/info/**" security="none"/>

<!-- Security Configuration for Faces Pages -->
<!-- Start Customization for Faces -->
<!-- ***************************** -->
<!-- Failure Login Handler -->
<bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="com.fg.ts.web.util.security.LoginFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/auth/login" />
</bean>

<!-- Faces Redirect -->
<bean id="facesRedirectStrategy" class="com.fg.ts.web.util.security.FacesRedirectStrategy">
    <property name="invalidSessionUrl" value="/auth/login/sessionExpired" />
</bean>
<!-- Shared Objects -->
<bean id="securityContextRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository" />
<bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />


<!-- Session Authentication Strategy -->
<bean id="sessionFixationAuthenticationStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy" />
<bean id="registerSessionStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
    <constructor-arg name="delegateStrategies">
        <list>
            <!-- <ref bean="concurrentSessionStrategy" /> -->
            <ref bean="sessionFixationAuthenticationStrategy" />
            <ref bean="registerSessionStrategy" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>


<!-- Remember-Me Service -->
<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <constructor-arg name="key" value="${encoder.password}" />
    <constructor-arg name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    <property name="parameter" value="j_remember_me" />
    <property name="cookieName" value="TMS_REME" />
</bean>

<!-- Filters -->
<bean id="usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" />
    <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices" />
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionManagementFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter">
    <constructor-arg name="securityContextRepository" ref="securityContextRepository" />
    <constructor-arg name="sessionStrategy" ref="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" />
    <property name="invalidSessionStrategy" ref="facesRedirectStrategy" />
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
</bean>
 <bean id="concurrentSessionFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <constructor-arg name="expiredUrl" value="/auth/login/expiredDueToConcurrentAccess" />
    <property name="redirectStrategy" ref="facesRedirectStrategy" />
</bean>

<bean id="authEntryPoint" class="com.fg.ts.web.util.security.FacesLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/auth/login"/>
</bean>
<!-- End Customization for Faces -->
<!-- ***************************** -->

<sec:http use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
          entry-point-ref="authEntryPoint"> <!--security-context-repository-ref="securityContextRepository"-->
    <sec:http-basic />


    <sec:custom-filter ref="usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter" before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="sessionManagementFilter" position="SESSION_MANAGEMENT_FILTER" />
    <sec:anonymous />
    <sec:remember-me key="${encoder.password}" services-ref="rememberMeServices" />
    <sec:form-login login-page="/auth/login" authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
    <sec:logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="TMS_SES,TMS_REME"
                logout-success-url="/auth/login" />


    <sec:session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />

    <!-- General Access Control -->
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/projects/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_PM')" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/assets/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_PM')" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/setup/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_PM')" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/tm/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_PM')" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/termBase/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_PM')" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/quality/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_PM')" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/editor/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</sec:http>
```

How can I make spring security use the session created by spring-session ?

Comment: What does your web.xml look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue, the reason was that in the FilterChain, `springSecurityFilterChain` Filter always loaded first before the `springSessionRepositoryFilter`, and so the Spring Session was not yet created, so the security filter created it's own.

this was happening because my `springSessionRepositoryFilter` was configured specifically for each servlet like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

but when I removed it and made it a global filter it then worked, much like this:

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```